# Регулярное выражение для BigDecimal Angular 2

Tags: регулярные-выражения, angular2

Я работаю на Ангуляр 2 и мне необходимо регулярное выражение для ввода суммы вида например:

100.00

У меня есть следующее регулярное выражение:

`\d+(\.\d{1,2})?`

Однако:

1. оно не всегда срабатывает
2. позволяет вводить следующую сумму 015.00

Помогите, пожалуйста, улучшить и исправить данное регулярное выражение.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте `/^[1-9]\d*(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/` — оно требует начала не с нуля, ограничивает ввод только нужным числом и признаёт только точку между цифрами (у вас используется метасимвол `.`, означающий любой знак кроме перевода строки). Также оно не запоминает часть в скобках (если этого, конечно, вам не нужно).